# How do I keep my tank from going haywire?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a moving tank: http://www.exeneva.com/html5/movingTankExample

Use the arrow keys to move the tank. There is currently no physics or rotation.

One problem is that if you press arrow keys too quickly, the tank is no longer centered on a tile and the animations get screwed up. I want to restrict the tank so that key presses don't affect the tank while it's currently in a movement/animation frame. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution.  You weren't running the animation a set number times per arrow press so I changed the setTimeout to do so.  As a note you may want to implement something where when a player is holding down on the arrow key it only calls the function if the tankState is "stopped" this way you don't end up with a lot of calls to the function that will end up with the tank shooting off in some direction.

```
function moveTank(dir) {
var steps=0, int = setInterval(function() {
steps++;
tankState = "moving";
if (dir == "up") {
tankMoveY = -4;
} else if (dir == "down") {
tankMoveY = 4;
} else if (dir == "left") {
tankMoveX = -4;
} else if (dir == "right") {
tankMoveX = 4;
}
tankX += tankMoveX;
tankY += tankMoveY;
animateMovement();
drawScreen();
if(steps==5){//set this to the number of steps you want the animation to run.
clearInterval(int);
tankMoveX = 0;
tankMoveY = 0;
tankState = "stopped";
}
},120);
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. I also added in the check to make sure the tank state is stopped. Thank you!